# php count between dates total value

Tags: php, date, time

I have the following code which counts between dates excluding weekends which works a treat.

Its looping through getting multiple dates from a database and outputs them individually. How would i go about adding all the loop results together to get a total number of days?

Here is my code:

```
$start = strtotime(get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'from_date', TRUE ));
$end = strtotime(get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'to_date', TRUE ));

$count = 0;

while(date('Y-m-d', $start) < date('Y-m-d', $end)){
  $count += date('N', $start) < 6 ? 1 : 0;
  $start = strtotime("+1 day", $start);
}

echo $count;
```

The above outputs the following:

```
1
1
1
3
3
```

I need to add these together so i get a total of 9

Comment: And what about sending last `$count` result into next func call? And use `$count = $_GET['current_count']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $count;
$runningTotal += $count;
```

Your running total is now in `$runningTotal`.

Comment: Well, that was not rocket science. Do not forget to tick the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

If you want return the number of days between two date or more, you can use as Query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('new_date', 'old_date');
```

Result is number of days.